# Resolving a «multiple possible bean candidates» conflict in Micronaut

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

I got this error while trying to create a custom `OpenIdAuthenticationMapper`. This code will make a request to an Oauth server to get the identification code and token. I don't know how to convert the `AuthenticationResponse.success` to `Publisher<AuthenticationResponse>`.

Micronaut: 4.2.1

```
ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Failed to inject value for parameter [authenticationMapper] of class: io.micronaut.security.oauth2.endpoint.authorization.response.DefaultOpenIdAuthorizationResponseHandler

Message: Multiple possible bean candidates found: [DefaultOpenIdAuthenticationMapper, MyOpenIdAuthenticationMapper]
```

```
@Singleton
@Named("my")
class MyOpenIdAuthenticationMapper(
    ...
) : OpenIdAuthenticationMapper {
    @NonNull
    override fun createAuthenticationResponse(
        providerName: String,
        tokenResponse: OpenIdTokenResponse,
        openIdClaims: OpenIdClaims,
        @Nullable state: State?
    ): Publisher<AuthenticationResponse> {
       # Make request to Oauth server
        ...

        val attributes = mapOf(
            ...
        )

        return Mono.create { AuthenticationResponse.success(identificationCode, emptyList(), attributes) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Micronaut finds two bean candidates of type `OpenIdAuthenticationMapper` in your application context and therefore it fails, because it does not know how to resolve that conflict.

To resolve this conflict you've got to help Micronaut using the following options:

**Mark your bean as the primary**

Use `@Primary` to tell Micronaut to choose your bean, to resolve the multiple possible bean candidates conflict.

```kotlin
@Singleton
@Primary
class MyOpenIdAuthenticationMapper : OpenIdAuthenticationMapper {}
```

**Replace the DefaultOpenIdAuthenticationMapper**

You can replace the `DefaultOpenIdAuthenticationMapper` with your implementation by adding `@Replace`

```kotlin
@Singleton
@Replaces(DefaultOpenIdAuthenticationMapper)
class MyOpenIdAuthenticationMapper : OpenIdAuthenticationMapper {}
```

to your class. This will make sure there is only one OpenIdAuthenticationMapper bean in the application context.

Further readings

- [The Micronaut Documentation](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#qualifiers)